# YouTube and Fancybox 2

Tags: web, youtube, fancybox-2

I am able to embed and view my YouTube videos in my website. The problem is: when MY videos finish, a YouTube screen appears with a number of OTHER PEOPLE'S videos as choices. I want the Fancybox pop-up to close when my video finishes so this doesn't happen. I have found a number of suggestions for closing the Fancybox pop-up when a YouTube video ends, but none of them work. I wonder if that's because they're written for Fancybox-1 and I'm using Fancybox-2. I've inserted the code below, but it doesn't trigger.

```
    <script>
    function onPlayerStateChange(event){
        if (event.data===0){
            $.fancybox.close();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this by adding `?rel=0` to the end of the URL which hides all related videos (more info on rel param [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#rel))

You can add `?rel=0` to each of your video URLs (manually), or have the fancybox beforeLoad function add it just before it opens: (example also sets autoplay to 1)

```
beforeLoad: function () {
    var url = $(this.element).attr("href");
    url += '?autoplay=1&rel=0';
    this.href = url;
}
```

(Note that this code adds it to all videos and wont work if `?` is already in the URL, so you may need to adjust the code to your page)

Comment: I wound up doing it in html with the same result. I used IE to look at source code of a website with videos that worked the way I wanted. I also googled "rel=0" for a better understanding.